# Modelbuilder variables to rename multiple shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.4

I'm using ArcGIS 10.4 and created a model to rename a shapefile.

It works fine if the model is running from ArcMap but for only one time. Once tried to run it again, it gives error because the file already renamed from the previous run.

How can I make the shapefile name variable every time I run the model?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What is in your model?  If it is just what you have described please show us a picture of it.  If it is more then can you make a test model to show us that still displays the issue, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to create a variable for the new shapefile name, then you can use "Parse Path". This is a model builder tool where an inline variable can be created and used through the model. You can set this as a model parameter so that the user can input the new shapefile name before running the model.

Please see [Parse Path (ArcGIS Desktop Help)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/parse-path.htm) for more info.

To insert the "Parse Path" tool, right click in the model builder window and go to "Model Only Tools" and "Parse Path".

[image]

Next, we need to set the "Input Data Element". This is where we tell the model what variable we are creating. This also needs to be set as a "Model Parameter" so that the user can change this each time the model is run.

[image]

Now, we need to set the "Parse Type" as "Name". Here we are telling the tool that we are creating a name variable.

[image]

We have now created a variable to use within the model. So within you model, where you are renaming your new output, you need to use %Value% as your new shapefile name. This will then change the name of the output, depending on what the user has inputted into the parameter before the model is run.